# Parse error when using function in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, anonymous-function

I'm trying to create an array of functions. Although, I'm getting `parse error` and nothing more when executing this code

```
protected $filter_functions = [
    "price" => function(&$query, $lower, $higher) {
        $query->where("price", ">=", $lower)->where("price", "<=", $higher);
    }
];
```

I can't see any syntax error but maybe there is. The PHP version is currently 5.6.28 and should be compatible with anonymous functions.

Comment: Are you using yii?

Comment: No, Laravel framework

Comment: I added that info to tags. Thank you

Comment: what about the logs; is there a more descriptive error?

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message...

Comment: You may want to move this declaration to the constructor or somewhere else, cause it's impossible to execute php code when declaring Class properties

Comment: @arkascha that is the **full error message**

Comment: I doubt that, actually. An error message in php comes at least with a line number. Usually also some more explanatory text. I ask for the full error message since the syntax of those lines is correct, except under certain circumstances.

Comment: @arkascha The syntaxt isn't correct, You may have to look closer

Comment: @Ayaou Works for me.

Comment: @Ayaou That did it. Thank you!

Comment: @arkascha In this case I use Laravel framework. Maybe there something wrong when rendering error cause all I got is `parse error`.

Comment: One does not rely on a _rendered_ error message in the output. Error messages are taken from the http servers error log file.

Comment: @arkascha in [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) it states that ` it must be able (a property declaration) to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information`

Comment: @Ayaou That certainly is true, but that is not a syntax error. That also is why I stated the "except under certain circumstances".

Comment: @arkascha It is certainly a syntax error. the error in this case would be `Error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in ...`

Comment: @arkascha this is what I get https://uploadpie.com/k68Fm6

Answer (score 0):

you must put this into the constructor

```
protected $filter_functions;

public function __construct(){
    $this->filter_functions = [
        "price" => function(&$query, $lower, $higher) {
            $query->where("price", ">=", $lower)->where("price", "<=", $higher);
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: `__constructor` that should most likely read as `__construct`. Unless Laravel uses `__constructor`. Edit: This comment as per original http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42370244/1

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers it uses `__construct` alright.

Comment: I think you also need to have `parent::__construct();` before you try to set `$this->filter_functions`, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: only if you this class extends from another but this is not clear based on the given example